# oReplace into a permanent new column in Teradata

Tags: sql, replace, special-characters, teradata

Using Teradata I have written some oReplace code to remove forward slashes '/' from my ID. The code works but produces a temporary column (in my answerset) - what I would like is to then be able to save the cleansed data as a new permanent column in my table, or alternatively just to overwrite the original column with the oReplace results.

The code I have written is as follows:

```
SELECT ID, oReplace(ID, '/','') As ID_TRIM from Database.table
```

Can anybody help me please to keep the results in my table with the / removed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE Database.table
SET ID = oReplace(ID, '/','')
WHERE ID LIKE '%/%'
```

For a single character `oTranslate` should be more efficient:

```
UPDATE Database.table
SET ID = oTranslate(ID, '/','')
WHERE ID LIKE '%/%'
```

Comment: Thanks dnoeth, you're a hero